# Moving TV and Appliances from US to Denmark

Tags: usa, relocation, denmark, television

My girlfriend and I are moving to Denmark next month. Our move is being paid for by her employer. I'm trying to decide what appliances are worth bringing. Is it worth bringing our 65" LCD tv and hooking it up to a transformer? Or should we sell large items here and just buy new ones there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague brought his TV from Canada to Denmark, and brought a transformer from Canada.  The TV caught fire after about a week, we assume because the transformer wasn't adequate -- check the cost of a suitable transformer! If you intend to watch broadcast TV (rather than just DVDs/laptop etc) also check if the TV is compatible with European standards. Cable TV requires a subscription, broadcast (radio waves, usually through an antenna on the roof and a socket in the wall) is 'free'.

Danish people would check http://www.pricerunner.dk/ for new appliances, http://www.elgiganten.dk/ is one of the large electronics stores. Prices are likely to be higher than in the USA.

Answer (score 8):

This may be a matter of opinion, but I'll give you my advice from personal experience. Buy everything there in Denmark. If your move is relatively temporary, as in just a couple of years, you can store that stuff. If your move is permanent, sell it. It is vastly less hassle and long-term cost to just get most of your standard electronics locally.

Comment: Thanks Ouflak. This is useful, it's the other option. Good to hear it from someone who's experienced it.

Answer (score 4):

Some electronic appliances can work with both 110V 60hz and 220V 50hz (e.g. most laptop & phones power supplies, televisions, etc.)

Check your TV specs: it may already be compatible with 220-240V 50hz that you find in Europe: you may just need a socket adapter.

Comment: If I went this route, my first choice would be to replace the cord that goes from the power outlet to the device with a new cord (Something like the one shown at https://www.amazon.com/Listed-Polarized-Power-Cord-Vizio-LED-TV-Smart-HDTV-Adapter-AC-Wall-Cable/dp/B00STU4UWM/ref=asc_df_B00STU4UWM/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=228696667650&hvpos=1o5&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1104998510076186508&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9003094&hvtargid=pla-388014299492&psc=1  

But get one for Denmark of course. Power adapters are notorious for poor quality.